# Android: add action to canvas draw objects

Tags: android, draw, rect

Can I display image button on canvas with action of opening another activity.
I am drawing splash rect on screen using canvas all well. But I also need to add Image button with some action or if not possible then drawtext with some action to open another activity. thanks...

[sample screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5xRd.png)

Comment: I don't understand. why you don't use `dialog` and `imageButton` on it?

Comment: splash is draw using canvas after end of a game & I can not tamper code created by senior. I need to add Image Button on splash & give action to open another activity or call another method.

Comment: Anyway, if you are using `draw` function, you can't handle `OnClickListener` and if you want to handle clicking on specific region, you have to handle `OnClickListener` on parent `view` and calculate by yourself to find it out *the click is in your region or not*

Comment: can onTouchEvent will help me ?

Comment: `OnTouch` or `OnClick`, whatever you want

Comment: thanks, that's look +ve. can you help me with some sample code.